NW.js nw-builder. Not Displaying Icon on macOS ARM64. Demo Project
I switched from nw-phoenix-builder to nw-builder because the latter has progressed while nw-phoenix-builder has become somewhat outdated. I thought I could easily get started with nw-builder, but I was mistaken. Before implementing it in my project, I wanted to understand how it works by creating a demo, but I couldn't find a similar one anywhere. If you know of any, I would appreciate your guidance.
Problem:
I built my project for ARM64 and successfully displayed the .icns icon, but the application icon itself remains blank. Can you help me with this?
Check out my repo here: https://github.com/me-vlad-k/nwbuilder-demo

The problem was with the .icns file itself. I had found a dummy icon somewhere on the web, and since it was created incorrectly, it caused this weird behavior.
Important
Make sure to create your .icns file correctly. When using an app to create a .icns file, you should start with a 1024x1024 PNG file to ensure everything looks sharp on Retina displays. If you somehow miss some icon dimensions, such as 64x64 or others, macOS will display blank icons instead of the missing ones.
There are many apps available on the web that can create .icns files for you. A few examples are iLove Icns Creator, Image2Icon, and many others, including command-line utilities.
